# Jenkins issue with docker push to private repo

Tags: jenkins, docker-registry, dcos

I'm running a jenkins server on my DC/OS, and also got a private registry in the same DC.

the private registry does not have any ssl certificate and to push images from my mac I used the following command

> ocker-machine ssh default "echo $'EXTRA_ARGS=\"--insecure-registry \"' | sudo tee -a /var/lib/boot2docker/profile && sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart"

so it worked fine.

on jenkins I tried to set the DOCKER_OPTS see https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/

but then I figured that the build is actually running on an agent, so how do I configure the jenkins worker to trust my private registry?

Comment: Are you aware of https://github.com/dcos/examples/tree/master/1.8/registry and tried this?

Comment: Use a json configuration file: `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. Works on almost every setup.
Add: 
`{..., "insecure-registries": [ "your registry" ], ...}`
[See the `--config-file` option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/)

Comment: You can place the file anywhere, but then you will have to start the docker deamon with the `config-file=/path/to/file.json` option. If you place the file at `/etc/docker/daemon.json` it is picked up without any change (probably need to restart the deamon).

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas Yes, I installed the registry this way, and successfully pushing images via ssh, but not via jenkins build.

Comment: @Rik I'll really appreciate a bit more of explanation, 10x.

Comment: I am having a hard time finding a reference, but [this](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-run-a-insecure-registry/9692) has an example even though it is for mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed the Jenkins from the Mesosphere Universe, then the default Jenkins agent container uses docker-in-docker.

See the DC/OS Jenkins service guide for how to configure docker run parameters to add environment variables: https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.8/usage/service-guides/jenkins/advanced-configuration/